# Non-Measure Theoretic Argument for Var(X) = 0 iff X is constant (X continuous RV)

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, expected-value, estimators

I am studying out of DeGroot and Schervish trying to carefully understand the math of prob/stats. In ch 4.3 on variance, they state the theorem that given X a RV whose mean and var exist, then Var(X) = 0 iff X is a constant.

The theorem itself is simple to understand: I am trying to get a firm grasp on how to prove it rigorously for the case where X is a continuous RV. The book gives a proof, which is not really self consistent with their treatment of expectations. I am thinking it is possible to prove this result (w/o the use of measure theory) via a tool they introduce earlier in which they use the fact that if $A_n$ are a collection of nested sets, then the limit of the probability that an even is in their intersection is the limit of the probability of $A_n$. (So in ths case, one could consider the collection of closed nested intervals $A_n$ = [c-$\frac{1}{n}$,c+$\frac{1}{n}$]. If one assume the pdf to be continuous then it seems you should be able to use this fact to argue that the limit of the expected values will be equal to the true expected value. I haven't covered limits of estimators though so even though I think intuitively this makes sense, I don't actually know if this method is rigorously correct.

Does this sound like a proper way to proceed?

TIA,
JZ

Comment: Are you referring to the proof of Theorem 4.3.3? What specifically about their proof do you find distasteful? It seems they just rely on their own Theorem 4.2.3, so I don't see how that isn't self consistent..

Comment: I have 5th edtn, and this is thm 4.3.1. The justification given is "comment given immediately following the proof of thm 4.2.2 on pg 191", which is the statement that "if Pr(X>=a)=1 and E(X)=a then it must be true that Pr(X>a)=0 and Pr(X=a)=1". BUT, they don't prove this theorem (although I think they could with the approach I suggested perhaps). And nowhere, do I see where they address how to deal with point probabilities for continuous distbtns (in fact they go out of their way to say that the probability of an event in dimension less than that of X is zero)

Comment: You need some amount of measure theory even to define random variables, expectations, and variance. Moreover, this theorem is false unless it is understood that $X$ is a constant *except possibly on a set of measure zero*. What, then, are you really looking for in a "non-measure theoretic argument"?

Comment: I'm a student, so please excuse my ignorance. I was trying to see if it was possible to construct such an argument. I appreciate your statement however, because this tells me that there is no such rigorous proof w/o the use of measure theory.

Comment: It might be easier to consider that no constant can be a continuous random variable. A constant can only be formulated as a discrete random variable with its entire probability mass at one point.

Comment: If $X$ is a constant, it is not a continuous rv.